# Spyder: refresh existing plot window instead of opening a new one

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I want to show plots in a separate window. Currently I have the IPython graphics backend set to "automatic".

When I re-run the code (or plot another figure), Spyder opens a new plot window. Is it possible to refresh the figure in the window that is already opened instead of opening a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI window that opens when you call `plt.show()` is bound to a figure. You cannot change the figure inside it. (Well, to be precise, there might be an option of obtaining a handle from the operating system and manipulating its content, but I assume this is not worth the effort.)

Re-running the code actually means that you produce a new figure since the code does not know that it's been run before.

So, exchanging the figure or reusing the window to plot a different figure is not possible.

What is possible however is to use the figure and manipulate the figure while it's open. This is done via `plt.ion()`. After calling this command in IPython you can adapt the figure, e.g. adding new lines to it etc.

See this example:

[image]

At  `IN [6]` the window opens and when `IN [7]` is executed, the figure stays open and the content changes.

Comment: Not the solution I was hoping for, but at least now I understand what's going on. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

Sure, it is possible with Spyder while in the same running kernel. Try the following example using num as parameter to `plt.figure()`, where num will always refer to the same figure and refresh it if already opened. Also works with `plt.subplots()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy import *
t = linspace(0, 0.1,1000)
w = rand(1)*60*2*pi

fig = plt.figure(num=10, clear=True, figsize = [10,8])
plt.plot(t,cos(w*t))
plt.plot(t,cos(w*t-2*pi/3))
plt.plot(t,cos(w*t-4*pi/3))
```